# Plotting subclassed model in tensorflow-2.0 beta

Tags: python, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0

I have a subclassed model that instantiates a few custom layers via subclassing.  I tried using `keras.utils.plot_model()` but all it does is print the model block, none of the layers appeared.

Can a Tensorflow expert comment on this?  Will this feature ever be implemented in the future?  If not, what is the next best alternative to examine the computation graph?  Note that `model.summary()` only gives a summary of the parameters of the custom layer, within which contains two dense layers.  Ideally, I like to see all the computations, if that is not asking too much...

**Update**: I dug into the source, looks like plot_model() first check for the `_is_graph_network` attribute.  Graph Networks are used in Functional and Sequential APIs.  From the source:

> Two types of `Networks` exist: Graph Networks and Subclass Networks. Graph
>    networks are used in the Keras Functional and Sequential APIs. Subclassed
>    networks are used when a user subclasses the `Model` class. In general,
>    more Keras features are supported with Graph Networks than with Subclassed
>    Networks, specifically:
>
> - Model cloning (`keras.models.clone()`)
> - Serialization (`model.get_config()/from_config()`, `model.to_json()/to_yaml()`)
> - Whole-model saving (`model.save()`)

(**custom graph component**)
Naturally, I like to know if I can build a graph network component, so my subclassed model/layer can work with these features.  Does that involve a lot of effort?

(**tf.function graph visualization**)
Can someone let me know if graph visualization via Tensorboard works with Tensorflow2 tf.functions?  In Tensorflow 1.x, one defines a name scope for a logical group of ops (e.g. generator/discriminator in GAN, encoder/decoder in VAE and loss/metrics), they are then displayed as a high-level block in the graph visualization.  Can I define something similar for tf.functions?

Comment: If anyone sees this and knows someone who can help, please let me know.  I really hope to find out more about the inner workings of tensorflow2.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you figured out how to plot the model created using subclassing technique?

Comment: @DavidKWH if you're still looking for the answer, I've posted a simple workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63898244/9215780).

Answer (score 2):

Accodring to the officical documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs,
you can

> use **TensorFlow Summary Trace API** to log autographed functions for
>   visualization in TensorBoard

Here is a simple example for visuliazing a subclassed model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import layers

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, num_classes=10):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__(name='my_model')
    self.num_classes = num_classes
    self.dense_1 = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')
    self.dense_2 = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid')

  def call(self, inputs): 
    x = self.dense_1(inputs)
    return self.dense_2(x)

model = MyModel(num_classes=10)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

data = np.random.random((1000, 32))
labels = np.random.random((1000, 10))

@tf.function
def trace():
  data = np.random.random((1, 32))
  model(data)


logdir = "trace_log"
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)
tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True, profiler=True)
# Forward pass
trace()
with writer.as_default():
  tf.summary.trace_export(name="model_trace", step=0, profiler_outdir=logdir)
```

Then you can use Tensorboard to examine the computation graph:

```
tensorboard --logdir trace_log
```