# How do I plot a Keras/Tensorflow subclassing API model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, plot, keras, deep-learning

I made a model that runs correctly using the Keras Subclassing API. The `model.summary()` also works correctly. When trying to use `tf.keras.utils.plot_model()` to visualize my model's architecture, it will just output this image:

[image]

This almost feels like a joke from the Keras development team. This is the full architecture:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GaussianDropout, GRU, Concatenate, Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)

data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y)).\
    shuffle(len(X)).\
    map(lambda x, y: (tf.divide(x, tf.reduce_max(x)), y))

training = data.take(400).batch(8)
testing = data.skip(400).map(lambda x, y: (tf.expand_dims(x, 0), y))

class NeuralNetwork(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = Dense(16, input_shape=(10,), activation='relu', name='Dense1')
        self.dense2 = Dense(32, activation='relu', name='Dense2')
        self.resha1 = Reshape((1, 32))
        self.gru1 = GRU(16, activation='tanh', recurrent_dropout=1e-1)
        self.dense3 = Dense(64, activation='relu', name='Dense3')
        self.gauss1 = GaussianDropout(5e-1)
        self.conca1 = Concatenate()
        self.dense4 = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='Dense4')
        self.dense5 = Dense(1, name='Dense5')

    def call(self, x, *args, **kwargs):
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        a = self.resha1(x)
        a = self.gru1(a)
        b = self.dense3(x)
        b = self.gauss1(b)
        x = self.conca1([a, b])
        x = self.dense4(x)
        x = self.dense5(x)
        return x


skynet = NeuralNetwork()
skynet.build(input_shape=(None, 10))
skynet.summary()

model = tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model=skynet,
         show_shapes=True, to_file='/home/nicolas/Desktop/model.png')
```

Comment: A basic strategy to plot the Model is to follow the lines given in the answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77235536/8844500

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've found some workaround to plot with the model sub-classing API. For the obvious reason **Sub-Classing** API doesn't support **Sequential or Functional** API like `model.summary()` and nice visualization using `plot_model`. Here, I will demonstrate both.

```py
class my_model(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, dim):
        super(my_model, self).__init__()
        self.Base  = keras.keras.applications.VGG16(
            input_shape=(dim), 
            include_top = False, 
            weights = 'imagenet'
        )
        self.GAP   = L.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.BAT   = L.BatchNormalization()
        self.DROP  = L.Dropout(rate=0.1)
        self.DENS  = L.Dense(256, activation='relu', name = 'dense_A')
        self.OUT   = L.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        x  = self.Base(inputs)
        g  = self.GAP(x)
        b  = self.BAT(g)
        d  = self.DROP(b)
        d  = self.DENS(d)
        return self.OUT(d)
    
    # AFAIK: The most convenient method to print model.summary() 
    # similar to the sequential or functional API like.
    def build_graph(self):
        x = Input(shape=(dim))
        return Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))

dim = (124,124,3)
model = my_model((dim))
model.build((None, *dim))
model.build_graph().summary()
```

It will produce as follows:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_67 (InputLayer)        [(None, 124, 124, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
vgg16 (Functional)           (None, 3, 3, 512)         14714688  
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_32  (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (Batch (None, 512)               2048      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_A (Dense)              (None, 256)               402192    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 785       
=================================================================
Total params: 14,848,321
Trainable params: 14,847,297
Non-trainable params: 1,024
```

Now by using the `build_graph` function, we can simply plot the whole architecture.

```py
# Just showing all possible argument for newcomer.  
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
    model.build_graph(),                      # here is the trick (for now)
    to_file='model.png', dpi=96,              # saving  
    show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True,  # show shapes and layer name
    expand_nested=False                       # will show nested block
)
```

It will produce as follows: -)

[image: a]

---

Similar QnA:

1. [Retrieving Keras Layer Properties from a tf.keras.Model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76265933/9215780)
2. [Visualize nested keras.Model (SubClassed API) GAN model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66891359/9215780)

Comment: I like the workaround. However, it only applies to simple models. As soon as a model is enclosed by another model, the nestings will not be resolved (i.e. a GAN where the generator and discriminator are implemented as `keras.Model` see [here](https://imgur.com/a/6Lkc1PW)). Setting `expand_nested=True` does not change the behavior. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure. But if possible please share some toy code to explore.

Comment: I asked a new question with a toy example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66887785/how-can-i-visualize-a-nested-keras-model-with-plot-model)

Comment: Your answer is substantial, well done!!!

Answer (score 4):

Another workaround: convert the savemodel format model to onnx using [tf2onnx](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx), then use [netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) to view the model architecture.

Here is part of the model in netron:
[image]

Comment: Sometimes using the netron app with .onnx models becomes too complicated for large models.

Answer (score 2):

**Update (04-Jan-2021): It seems this is possible; see @M.Innat's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63898244/2099607).**

---

It could not be done because basically model sub-classing, as it is implemented in TensorFlow, is limited in features and capabilities compared to the models created using Functional/Sequential API (which are called Graph networks in TF terminology). If you check the `plot_model` source code, you would see [the following check](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dc8f74544578756bad9d62f18349b35e31fba30a/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/vis_utils.py#L132-L135) in `model_to_dot` function (which is called by `plot_model`):

```
if not model._is_graph_network:
  node = pydot.Node(str(id(model)), label=model.name)
  dot.add_node(node)
  return dot
```

As I mentioned, the sub-classed models are not graph networks and therefore only a node containing the model name would be plotted for these models (i.e. the same thing you observed).

This has been already discussed in a [Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31647) and one of the developers of TensorFlow confirmed this behavior by giving the following argument:

> @omalleyt12 commented:
>
> Yes in general we can't assume anything about the structure of a subclassed Model. If your Model can be though of as blocks of Layers and you wish to visualize it like that, we recommend you view the Functional API

Answer (score 0):

I created a github repository demostrating my solution: https://github.com/Meidozuki/light-keras-plot
I've met the same problem several times. At the first, I use `Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))` ,too. But as time goes, everytime I want to plot a new model, I need to change the shape of input, so I find a way to automatically catch the input shape.
I let it to only display one time.
Use

```
@plotable()
def build(self,input_shape):
    super().build(input_shape)
```

where

```
def plotable(silent=False):
    '''
    Used on model.build to call tf.keras.utils.plot_model
    '''
    
    def decorate(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self,input_shape):
            result=func(self,input_shape)

            if not silent:
                from tensorflow.keras import layers
                from IPython.display import display
                if isinstance(input_shape,(tuple,tf.TensorShape)):
                    inputs=layers.Input(input_shape[1:])
                elif isinstance(input_shape,list):
                    inputs=[layers.Input(s[1:]) for s in input_shape]
                else:
                    raise AssertionError

                outputs=self.call(inputs)
                model=tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=outputs)
                display(tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model,show_shapes=True))
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorate
```