# How to visualize nested `tf.keras.Model (SubClassed API)` GAN model with plot_model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Models implemented as subclasses of `keras. Model` can generally not be visualized with `plot_model`. There is a workaround as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427583/how-do-i-plot-a-keras-tensorflow-subclassing-api-model). However, it only applies to simple models. As soon as a model is enclosed by another model, the nestings will not be resolved.

I am looking for a way to resolve nested models implemented as subclasses of the `keras. Model`. As an example, I have created a minimal GAN model:

```py
import keras
from keras import layers
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model


class BaseModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        super(BaseModel, self).call(inputs=inputs, training=training, mask=mask)

    def get_config(self):
        super(BaseModel, self).get_config()

    def build_graph(self, raw_shape):
        """ Plot models that subclass `keras.Model`

        Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427583/how-do-i-plot-a-keras-tensorflow-subclassing-api-model

        :param raw_shape: Shape tuple not containing the batch_size
        :return:
        """
        x = keras.Input(shape=raw_shape)
        return keras.Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))


class GANModel(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, generator, discriminator):
        super(GANModel, self).__init__()
        self.generator = generator
        self.discriminator = discriminator

    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False, mask=None):
        x = self.generator(input_tensor)
        x = self.discriminator(x)
        return x


class DiscriminatorModel(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, name="Critic"):
        super(DiscriminatorModel, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.l1 = layers.Conv2D(64, 2, activation=layers.ReLU())
        self.flat = layers.Flatten()
        self.dense = layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs, training=False, mask=None):
        x = self.l1(inputs, training=training)
        x = self.flat(x)
        x = self.dense(x, training=training)
        return x


class GeneratorModel(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, name="Generator"):
        super(GeneratorModel, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.dense = layers.Dense(128, activation=layers.ReLU())
        self.reshape = layers.Reshape((7, 7, 128))
        self.out = layers.Conv2D(1, (7, 7), activation='tanh', padding="same")

    def call(self, inputs, training=False, mask=None):
        x = self.dense(inputs, training=training)
        x = self.reshape(x)
        x = self.out(x, training=training)
        return x


g = GeneratorModel()
d = DiscriminatorModel()

plot_model(g.build_graph((7, 7, 1)), to_file="generator_model.png",
           expand_nested=True, show_shapes=True)

gan = GANModel(generator=g, discriminator=d)
plot_model(gan.build_graph((7, 7, 1)), to_file="gan_model.png", 
           expand_nested=True, show_shapes=True)
```

---

## Edit

Using the functional keras API I get the desired result (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRchO.jpg)). The nested models are correctly resolved within the GAN model.

```py
from keras import Model, layers, optimizers
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model


def get_generator(input_dim):
    initial = layers.Input(shape=input_dim)

    x = layers.Dense(128, activation=layers.ReLU())(initial)
    x = layers.Reshape((7, 7, 128))(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(1, (7, 7), activation='tanh', padding="same")(x)

    return Model(inputs=initial, outputs=x, name="Generator")


def get_discriminator(input_dim):
    initial = layers.Input(shape=input_dim)

    x = layers.Conv2D(64, 2, activation=layers.ReLU())(initial)
    x = layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = layers.Dense(1)(x)

    return Model(inputs=initial, outputs=x, name="Discriminator")

def get_gan(input_dim, latent_dim):
    initial = layers.Input(shape=input_dim)

    x = get_generator(input_dim)(initial)
    x = get_discriminator(latent_dim)(x)

    return Model(inputs=initial, outputs=x, name="GAN")



m = get_generator((7, 7, 1))
m.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam())

plot_model(m, expand_nested=True, show_shapes=True, to_file="generator_model_functional.png")

gan = get_gan((7, 7, 1), (7, 7, 1))
plot_model(gan, expand_nested=True, show_shapes=True, to_file="gan_model_functional.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you pass each `generator` and `discriminator` to  `GANModel`, they act like an encompassed child layer consisting of `n` times layers. So, if you plot only the `generator` model by the `GANModel` instances, it will show as follows (same goes to `discriminator`) unlike plots while using them separately.

The fact is while we pass data at this point using the `call()` method of `GANModel`, the **input** passes **implicitly** all internal layers (`generator`, `discriminator`) according to its design. Here I will show you two workaround for this to get your desired plot.

[image]

---

### Option 1

I believe you probably guess the method. In the `GANModel` model, we will pass the `input` very **explicitly** to each internal layer of those child layers (`generator`, `discriminator`).

```
class GANModel(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, generator, discriminator):
        super(GANModel, self).__init__()
        self.generator = generator
        self.discriminator = discriminator

    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False, mask=None):
        x = input_tensor

        for gen_lyr in self.generator.layers:
            print(gen_lyr) # checking 
            x = gen_lyr(x)

        for disc_lyr in self.discriminator.layers:
            print(disc_lyr) # checking 
            x = disc_lyr(x)

        return x
```

If you plot now, you will get

```
# All Internal Layers of self.generator, self.discriminator
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f2a472a3710>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Reshape object at 0x7f2a461e8f50>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f2a44591f90>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f2a47317290>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Flatten object at 0x7f2a47317ed0>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f2a57f42910>
```

[image]

---

### Option 2

I think it's a bit ugly approach. First, we take each internal layer and build a `Sequential` model with them. Then use `.build` to create its input layer. BOOM.

```
gan = GANModel(generator=g, discriminator=d)

all_layer = []
for layer in gan.layers: 
    all_layer.extend(layer.layers)

gan_plot = tf.keras.models.Sequential(all_layer)
gan_plot.build((None,7,7,1))
list(all_layer)

[<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x7f2a461ab390>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Reshape at 0x7f2a46156110>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D at 0x7f2a461fedd0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D at 0x7f2a461500d0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Flatten at 0x7f2a4613ea10>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x7f2a462cae10>]
```

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(gan_plot, expand_nested=True, show_shapes=True)
```

Comment: Thank youfor your reply. I appreciate your efforts. I am still not convinced as I am losing the structure for nested models. PS: I edited my question to show how smoothly it works with the functional API.

Comment: I see. Let me explain. In **functional API**, we usually use `layers. Input` which basically a **spec layer** rather than a real **trainable layer**. In your edited part, you used them (**3** times) to build each block of layers. And so the `keras` will plot according to this **model definition**.

Comment: Now, go back to your **subclassing API**, you won't see any `layers. Input`.  But except in one place, in the `build_graph` method. The way you define your model definition in the `call` method, `keras` will plot in that way.